# JNDI lookup failed (NameNotFoundException)

Tags: java, jetty, jndi, c3p0

**UPDATE**: Well, it seems that this is a problem only when I try to debug locally. When published on Jetty (not the same machine) it works great. Is it possible to configure the jetty.xml file used by Run-Jetty-Run when debugging locally?

I just wasted an afternoon trying to find the cause of this, but with no success...

I'm setting up a connection pool with c3p0 for my application. I'm using Jetty 7, by the way. The problem is that when I do a context.lookup get a datasource, I get this exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/jdbc/DSTest'
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:665)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:680)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:113)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.see.metrics.SqlHelper.Initialize(SqlHelper.java:68)
at com.see.metrics.Metrics.Initialize(Metrics.java:45)
at com.see.game.GameProducer.generateMetadata(GameProducer.java:223)
at org.odata4j.producer.mongodb.MongoProducer.initMongo(MongoProducer.java:98)
at org.odata4j.producer.mongodb.MongoProducerFactory.create(MongoProducerFactory.java:55)
at org.odata4j.producer.resources.ODataProducerProvider.newProducerFromFactory(ODataProducerProvider.java:66)
at org.odata4j.producer.resources.ODataProducerProvider.getInstance(ODataProducerProvider.java:48)
at org.odata4j.producer.resources.ODataProducerProvider.getInstance(ODataProducerProvider.java:1)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.LazySingletonContextProvider.get(LazySingletonContextProvider.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.LazySingletonContextProvider.access$000(LazySingletonContextProvider.java:52)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml.LazySingletonContextProvider$1.getValue(LazySingletonContextProvider.java:69)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.AbstractHttpContextInjectable$1.getValue(AbstractHttpContextInjectable.java:100)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:166)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1048)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have a **jndi.properties** file to configure my InitialContext (located in my resource folder src/main/resources)

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi
java.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory
```

I also have a **jetty-env.xml** file in the webapp/WEB-INF folder:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<!--<Set name="ConfigurationClasses">
   <Ref id="plusConfig"/>
</Set>  -->

<!-- MySql datasource org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource Factory-->
<New id="DSTest" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
    <Arg>
     <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
        <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://host/</Set>
        <Set name="username">username</Set>
        <Set name="password">password</Set>
        <Set name="checkoutTimeout">5000</Set>
        <Set name="initialPoolSize">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30</Set>
        <Set name="maxPoolSize">160</Set>
        <Set name="minPoolSize">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxStatements">200</Set>
        <Set name="maxConnectionAge">0</Set>
        <Set name="acquireIncrement">15</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
 </New>
</Configure>
```

And I added those lines in my **web.xml** file:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTest</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I seem to have followed all the required steps, but I still get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException when doing the lookup...

Any hints?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I forgot to put how I do my lookup.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DSTest");
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm silly, but try "jdbc/DSTest" as the JNDI name, not "env/jdbc/DSTest".

Comment: Just tried it, but no luck :/

Comment: Are you using Jetty 7 or Jetty 6? It looks like org.mortbay got changed to org.eclipse in Jetty 7, yet your Resource defintion class is still org.mortbay. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Stupid question but this page http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JNDI#JNDI-resref states that using JNDI with Jetty is an optional feature that needs to be enabled.

Specifically it says *The class that does this is org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration, and we specify its name in the list of configurations to be applied to the webapp when we define the org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext for it.*

Comment: Yeah, my Jetty as been configured. Thanks though :)